# This syntax is not working in my excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

```
=IF(AND($D10=5,$G10>=3),"IV"),IF(AND($D10=4,$G10>=4),"IV"),IF(AND(OR($D10=3,$D10=2),$G10=5),"IV"),IF(AND($D10=5, $G10<=2),"III"),IF(AND(OR($G10=3,$G10=2),$D10=4),"III"),IF(AND(OR($G10=3,$G10=4),$D10=3),"III"),IF(AND($D10=2,$G10=4),"III"),IF(AND($D10=3, $G10<=2),"II"),IF(AND(OR($G10=3,$G10=2),$D10=2),"II"),IF(AND($D10=4,$G10=1),"II"),IF(AND($D10=1,$G10>=3),"II"),"I")
```

To accomplish this

If columns `(D,G)=(5,5),(5,4),(5,3),(4,5),(4,4),(3,5) and (2,5)` then assign `IV`
If columns `(D,G)=(5,2),(5,1),(4,3),(4,2),(3,4), (3,3) and (2,4)` then assign `III`
If columns `(D,G)=IV(4,1),(3,2),(3,1),(2,3),(2,2),(1,5),(1,4) and (1,3)` then assign `II`
If columns `(D,G)=(2,1), (1,2) and (1,1)` then assign `I`

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question currently doesn't refer to what you need help with. Please edit your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, but I will guess what you mean.
I think you want to get the results in my column H.

[image]

For this, I used in row 10 the formula

```
=IF(AND($D10=5,$G10>=3),"IV",IF(AND($D10=4,$G10>=4),"IV",IF(AND(OR($D10=3,$D10=2),$G10=5),"IV",IF(AND($D10=5, $G10<=2),"III",IF(AND(OR($G10=3,$G10=2),$D10=4),"III",IF(AND(OR($G10=3,$G10=4),$D10=3),"III",IF(AND($D10=2,$G10=4),"III",IF(AND($D10=3, $G10<=2),"II",IF(AND(OR($G10=3,$G10=2),$D10=2),"II",IF(AND($D10=4,$G10=1),"II",IF(AND($D10=1,$G10>=3),"II","I")))))))))))
```

(copy-paste in row 11).

In row 12 I used

```
=INDIRECT("R"&TEXT($G12+row($B$3)-1,"0")&"C"&TEXT($D12+COLUMN($B$3)-1,"0"),FALSE)
```

which relies on the table above.

None of the formulas check that 1 <= col D,G <=  5, you would have to add that if needed.

Answer (score -1):

If ( OR( (D,G)=(5,5), (D,G)=(5,4), (D,G)=(5,3), (D,G)=(4,5), (D,G)=(4,4), (D,G)=(3,5), (D,G)=(2,5) ), "IV",

If ( OR( (D,G)=(5,2), (D,G)=(5,1), (D,G)=(4,3, (D,G)=(4,2, (D,G)=(3,4, (D,G)=(3,3, (D,G)=(2,4) ), "III",

If columns (D,G)=IV(4,1),(3,2),(3,1),(2,3),(2,2),(1,5),(1,4) and (1,3) then assign II

```
here you lost me as how to interpret that "IV (4,1)
```

If ( OR( (D,G)=(2,1, (D,G)=(1,2), (D,G)=(1,1) ), "I","ERR" ) ) ) )

for each set of (D,G)=(5,5) above, put what you have already coded as AND($D10=5,$G10>=3) and so on.

One line is not coded by me due to the lack of clarity about IV, hope you would make that out yourself, or comment below so that I explain further.

However you said above that (D,G)=(5,5), but your formula is testing $D10=5,$G10>=3, that is >= instead of =, such things will give different results.

Comment: Why the downvote? Anything wrong in this?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but you need to remove the ")" in front of the "," that is in front of the IF:

=IF(AND($D1=5,$G1>=3),"IV",IF(AND($D1=4,$G1>=4),"IV",IF(AND(OR($D1=3,$D1=2),$G1=5),"IV",IF(AND($D1=5,$G1<=2),"III",IF(AND(OR($G1=3,$G1=2),$D1=4),"III",IF(AND(OR($G1=3,$G1=4),$D1=3),"III",IF(AND($D1=2,$G1=4),"III",IF(AND($D1=3,$G1<=2),"II",IF(AND(OR($G1=3,$G1=2),$D1=2),"II",IF(AND($D1=4,$G1=1),"II",IF(AND($D1=1,$G1>=3),"II","I")))))))))))